# Change character to encoding windows-1251

Tags: java, spring-boot, character-encoding

I have a problem with this character: ł
This is the code that I'm using:

```
String character = "ł";

String utf8String = "";
try {
    utf8String = new String(character.getBytes("UTF-8"), "windows-1251");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("character: " + utf8String);
```

but when I print the character, this is the result:

```
Character: E,
```

But this is not the character to display, does anyone see the error?

Comment: Strings are Unicode, so they don't have a character set *(they are UTF-16, but that doesn't matter here)*. Character sets are used when reading bytes into a string (e.g. input from console) or writing bytes from a string (e.g. output to console). If the output of `System.out.println("ł");` is not `ł`, then you very likely used the wrong character set when you **compiled** the Java source code.

Comment: My problem is that I receive that character from one system, and I have to send it to another system that only understands the windows-1251 encoding. With this character they are having problems and the system replaces it with: '?'

Comment: You can't (certainly *shouldn't*) fix it by creating a `String` from a `String`. You need to check the code that creates the `String` from the data (bytes) received from the original system, and to check the code that sends the `String` to the next system as bytes. The error occurs in one (or both) of those places. Characters sets are applied when converting bytes to/from `String` objects, so look for and fix the code that actually causes the problem, don't try a **hack** solution, which is what you're doing in this code. In short, fix the problem, not the symptom.

Comment: **1.**. For `"ł"` (_Latin Small Letter L With Stroke_) `character.getBytes("UTF-8")` yields `197` and `130`; decoding them to `"windows-1251"` then gives `Е‚` (_Cyrillic Capital Letter Ie_ and _Single Low-9 Quotation Mark_).  **2.** Generally, you can't get `Cyrillic` from `Latin`…

Comment: So what solution do you recommend me to do?